# With what kind of tag can we describe knight vs bishop endgames?

Tags: discussion, tags

(In some ways, this is a question about both chess stackex and chess/chess960 in general.)

---

Consider this post: [Interesting knight vs bishop endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35502/interesting-knight-vs-bishop-endgame)

**Question**: what tag could possibly describe 1 knight vs 1 bishop endgame?

Some thoughts/observations:

1. There doesn't seem to be a specific tag for knight vs bishop or minor piece endgames in general. Closest I found is [rook-and-minor-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rook-and-minor-endgame).
2. While in lots of [endgame courses](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/practical-endgame-resources-whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-series-in-chess), there are specific sections about knight vs bishop games, perhaps tags like [knight-and-bishop-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knight-and-bishop-endgame), [minor-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minor-endgame) and even [knight-vs-bishop-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knight-vs-bishop-endgame) aren't very good tags because these may include things that are like late middlegame or something.
3. To be fair, it's sad but lichess doesn't even have a tag like this (even though they have [queen and rook endgame tag](https://lichess.org/training/queenRookEndgame)). I can't think of a way for lichess to do this though. If they did have like a knight-and-bishop-endgame or minor-piece-endgame tag, then probably there will be things like 2 knights vs 2 bishops or knight and bishop vs 2 bishops and then somehow these are like late middlegame or something (no rooks or queens but still counts as late middlegame? hmmm...) instead of the usual like 1 knight vs 1 bishop like you see in the josh waitzkin endgame series in chessmaster.
4. But we're humans not computers though. Lichess I guess will have difficulty to identify that it's exactly 1 knight vs exactly 1 bishop, but as humans I figure we can correctly tag posts that are just like 1 bishop vs 1 knight if we go for [knight-vs-bishop-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knight-vs-bishop-endgame)
5. Both chess stackex and lichess have each of a knight endgame tag and a bishop endgame tag: [knight-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knight-endgame), [bishop-endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bishop-endgame), [lichess bishop](https://lichess.org/training/bishopEndgame), [lichess knight](https://lichess.org/training/knightEndgame)

Comment: Do we really need one?

Comment: @Herb well...'in lots of endgame courses, there are specific sections about knight vs bishop games,'

Comment: Potentially use End Game Table Base labelling eg NvB , NBQvBBRR etc 
Dont think that it would be overly helpful though from a searching perspective though.

Comment: @Herb oh wait incomplete response. i meant to add however that lichess technically doesn't have a kind of tag like that either. eh